# How to make my program to swap the columns when sorting a row, in a 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I made a program which sorts a bi-dimensional array last row, and it works, but what I want it to do is to swap the columns of the sorted digit, for example:
when I input:

```
5 8 7
9 5 4
6 2 1
```

to output:

```
7 8 5
4 5 9
1 2 6
```

It's mandatory to use the selection method.
Here is the code:

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
   int n,m,i,j,ni,nj;
   int A[99][99];
   int aux;

   cout<< "Lines : "; cin>>n;
   cout<< "Columns : "; cin>>m;

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0; j<m;j++)
    {
       cout<<"A["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]";
       cin>>A[i][j];
    }
    for(i=n-1;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0; j<m;j++){
     for(ni = i;ni<n;ni++){
     for(nj = j;nj<m;nj++){
    {
         if(A[i][j] > A[ni][nj])
         {
            aux = A[ni][nj];
            A[ni][nj] = A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = aux;

         }

    }
     }
     }
    }

    }
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the criteria, to decide that a column is *lower* than another one?

Comment: you dont need to sort the column just to move it along with the row

Comment: To swap two columns:  `std::swap(A[ni][nj];`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is not working, it gives me an error

Comment: The [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function is part of the standard library, so it has been fully tested.  What is the error and how is that statement not working?

Comment: The array must be writeable, e.g. non-`const`.  Also, verify that you are not working on a copy and passing a copy.  Did you print the two slots after they were swapped?  What did the debugger show?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it doesnt work because you gave it just 1 parameter

Comment: What would you do to sort a *single* row (the last one)? Well, at some point in that algorithm you'd swap two elements (of the last row), but what you have to do there instead is to write a (single) loop that would swap *all* the elements in those columns. Could you please edit the question fixing the indentation of the posted snippet? You might find out that a `;` is missing.